# how to send audio stream between child processes in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do i properly send stream to a child process. I am trying to stream audio from client to server using this method

I am getting the audio stream from client

```
const ss = require('socket.io-stream');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');

server = http.createServer(app);
io = socketIo(server);

const child_process = childProcess.fork('./child_process.js');


io.on('connect', (client) => {


    // when the client sends 'stream-transcribe' events
    // when using audio streaming
    ss(client).on('stream-transcribe', function(stream, data) {
     
    var combine_data = {
            "data": data,
            "stream": stream,
            "event":"new_stream"
          }
    
     child_process.send(combine_data)


  }


}
```

this call

```
     child_process.send(combine_data)
```

throws the error

> node:internal/child_process/serialization:127
> const string = JSONStringify(message) + '\n';
> ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'Namespace'
|     property 'server' -> object with constructor 'Server'
|     property 'nsps' -> object with constructor 'Object'
--- property '/' closes the circle
at stringify ()
at writeChannelMessage (node:internal/child_process/serialization:127:20)
at ChildProcess.target._send (node:internal/child_process:837:17)
at ChildProcess.target.send (node:internal/child_process:737:19)
at Socket. (/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/app/server.js:236:40)
at Socket.onstream (/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/app/node_modules/socket.io-stream/lib/socket.js:184:14)
at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
at Socket. (/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/app/node_modules/component-bind/index.js:21:15)
at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
at /Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/app/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:528:12

Node.js v17.5.0

what is causing the error and how can I send the stream to child_process ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with child processes, but I assume it's a similar concept to [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), where data between threads is copied and interpreted instead of shared. If that is true, then that would mean that you can't share references to streams between processes, but instead would either have to receive the stream in the child process and handle stream there.

Comment: can you clear question little bit, how does your `child_process.js` gets audio ? using stdin (standard input) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any data you send using `child_process.send()` will be converted to a string using `JSON.stringify()`. The data you try to send is too complex to be converted to a string. In particular, it uses circular references. You can easily verify this using `console.log()` or a debugger.

You can try to send only data that can be converted to a string. You probably should not try to send `stream` at all and only send the relevant fields of `data`.

Otherwise, you can probably `pipe()` the stream to `stdin` of the child process.

Based on the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream#usage):

```js
ss(client).on('stream-transcribe', function(stream, data) {
  stream.pipe(child_process.stdin);
});
```

In the child process you can read the data from `stdout`, which is a [readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readable-streams).

```js
child_process.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
  // do something with `chunk`
});
```

Comment: how do i access the stream in childprocess

Comment: @e.iluf See my updated answer.